# Adding form to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have blog model with `public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }` and comment model. I have created view for article (Details view) and I want to show everything from model blog (not problem) and comments to article to and after comments then show form for adding comment to blog (not in other page, I want it in the view with blog).

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string Body { get; set; }   
    public ICollection<Comments>Comments {get;set;}
}

public class Comments
{
    public int BlogPostID { get; set; }  
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }  
    public virtual BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model projectMvc.Model.BlogPost;

<div>
    
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => mode.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body )
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Movie.Body )
        </dd
    </dl>
</div>
@if (Model.Comments != null)
{
    foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Comment", comment)
    }
}
```

It shows the blog data and there is partial view for all comments to blog. And now I am not sure how to add form for adding comments.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add comments you can add below syntax in your view for displaying textbox for adding comment and button for submitting comments

```
<div class="AddComment" style="margin-left: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">  
                   <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "comment", post.BlogPostID)" class="form-control"  placeholder="Add a Comment ..."  style="display: inline;" />  
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addComment" data-id="@post.PostID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  
               </div>  
  
           </div>
```

After that on click of button you can call appropriate action from the controller using ajax

```
$('.addComment').on('click', function () {  
  
                var postId = $(this).attr('data-id');  
                var commentMsg = $('#comment_' + postId).val();  
                var dateTimeNow = new Date();  
                  
                //alert('Hello');  
                var comment = {  
                    CommentMsg: commentMsg,  
                    CommentedDate: dateTimeNow.toLocaleString()  
                };  
  
                $.ajax({  
  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddComment", "Comments")',  
                    data: { comment, postId },  
                    success: function (response) {  
  
                        $('div[class=allComments_' + postId + ']').remove();  
  
                        var allCommentsArea = $('<div>').addClass('allComments_' + postId);  
                        allCommentsArea.html(response);  
  
                        allCommentsArea.prependTo('#commentsBlock_' + postId);  
                         
                    },  
                    error: function (response) {  
                        alert('Sorry: Something Wrong');  
                    }  
  
                });  
  
            });
```

Comment: Thank you,but i have  a collection of comments and i can't access the properties to make a form with name,date,etc.

Comment: You do not need to access the comment properties to make form. You can see in my above examples, I am not binding with any model. I only used normal HTML elements and on click of button , I am executing a Jquery/Ajax call.